# Expose port 80 as user node in Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I wrote a NodeJS server which I’m trying to run in a node-alpine based Docker container.

as [Docker Node best practices](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#non-root-user), I’m using the node user.

I’m currently using port 9999, which works fine.

I would like to expose port 80 and 443 instead, but I can’t seem to get it to work.

The quick fix would be to simply use the root user instead, but that seems like a hacky solution.

The main question is:

- Can port 80 and 443 be exposed by the node user? If so, how?

This also raises some additional questions:

- Would it be better to just stick with the root user instead?
- Is it a good idea to expose ports 80 and 443 in a Docker image?

For what it’s worth, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
COPY api api
COPY packages/utils packages/utils
COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock
RUN npm uninstall --global npm \
 && apk add build-base python2 --no-cache \
 && yarn --frozen-lockfile --production \
 && rm -r /opt/yarn* yarn.lock
USER node
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "-r", "esm", "api/server.js"]
EXPOSE 9999
```

Comment: You can't run node app on port bellow 1024 without superuser priviliges. Also running node as root is a bad idea. You should use reverse proxy such as nginx.

Comment: ...but when you run the image, you can pick an arbitrary port on the host to use; for instance `docker run -p 80:9999` will publish the port on the normal HTTP port 80 on the host.

Comment: I know I can map the exposed port to any arbitrary port on the host or using nginx. I just figured it would make sense to expose an HTTP server on the default port on the container. From the look of the comments so far, it appears I was wrong.